# How can I distinguish if a menu is opened or closed in the ToolStripMenuItem EventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms

Adding an event handler to a `ToolStripMenuItem` like this:

```
foo = new ToolStripMenuItem( title, image, EVENT_HANDLER );
```

then the `EVENT_HANDLER` is called when the menu has been clicked

1. to open, or
2. to close the menu item.

**My question:**

How can I distinguish in the `EVENT_HANDLER` if the event was triggered because the menu is going to be closed?

**Update:**

I am **not** talking about `ToolStripDropDown`.

Comment: Try using a variable and the DropDownOpening and DropDownClosed events to keep track of the status.  You won't get it from the Clicked event.

Comment: @LarsTech I tried it BUT the problem is `DropDownClosed` is triggered **after** the `EventHandler` so I still don't know if the menu is going to be closed.

Comment: Like I said, you won't get it from the Clicked event.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes, you were right. I use `DropDownOpening` which is triggered **before** the `EventHandler`. There I set a variable which I check in the `EventHandler`. If the variable is **not** set then the click came from *closing* the menu. Thx a lot for your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably won't be able to get that information from the Clicked event.

A work-around would be to use a variable for tracking the status and using the menu's `DropDownOpening` and `DropDownClosed` events to keep track of the open status of the menu.